# How can I get the last value from my picklist? It removes my "1". Work with TRIM

Tags: formula, administration

I have a few values:

```
5T-7T
7T-12T
12T-22T
22T-145T
```

I use that formula to get my last value:

`TRIM(RIGHT(TEXT(Items__c), FIND("-", TEXT(Items__c))-1))`

It works but when my second value starts at "1", it removes this "1". So I get:

```
7T
2T
22T
45T
```

How can I fix that? And how can I delete `T` too?

Answer (score 3):

Use MID(text, start, len) to select text within boundries, you were using RIGHT(len) which selects the right size of the text,  this caused you ill effects  since you did not include the length of the string ie. LEN(text)

Here are a list of more TEXT functions:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions.htm&type=5#text_operators

```
MID(
    TEXT(Items__c),
    FIND("-", TEXT(Items__c))+1,
    LEN(TEXT(Items__c))-FIND("-", TEXT(Items__c))
    )
```

Comment: Could you provide some educational commentary in your answer as to why this solves the original problem?